# Show that the spectral norm of one matrix is smaller than the other.

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

> Given matrices
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>         1/3 & 1/2 & 1 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> and
>
> $$B = \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 1/2 \\
>         1/2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>         1/3 & 1/2 & 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> show that $\| B \|_2 > \| A \|_2$ without actually calculating the largest (in absolute value) eigenvalues.

Since for symmetric matrices:

$$\| M \|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} |x^{t}Mx|$$

I've tried to show that the set $|x^{t}Ax|$ is dominated by the set $|x^{t}Bx|$, but without success. I have also tried to relate to the Frobenius norm since the Frobenius norm of $B$ is clearly bigger than that of $A$, but I can't make the inequalities between Frobenius and spectral norm work properly for this. In fact, I have calculated the spectral norms of both matrices: for $A$ it is 1.1667 and for $B$ it is 1.2676. The closeness between these values also suggests a finer argument is needed than just converting to the Frobenius norm.

Note: I want to do this problem without actually calculating the norms because this is only the first instance of a class of similar problems for larger matrix sizes. The question is from trying to understand the corresponding claim, made as though obvious, in [0509153](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0509153) (Example: Ordered Searching 2).

Comment: Sorry, I was referring specifically to the line "The spectral norm of the query matrices ... is maximized when ...". The inequality in my question is essentially a case of this maximization claim. $\Gamma_i$ is defined in Eqn.9.

Comment: I think they are using [Gershgorin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). Note that both matrices have only zeros on the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try using that.

Comment: Looks like the Perron-Frobenius theorem and the Collatz-Wielandt ratio could be useful here. Both your matrices are nonnegative and irreducible.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried these approaches with no success...